# Store DataSet when ending looping in C#

Tags: c#, list, dataset

I am using this code to fill DataSet

```
var ds = new DataSet();
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grdInterPOList.Rows)
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = row.Cells[0] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(chk.Value) == true)
        if (row.Cells.Count >= 2 && row.Cells[1].Value != null) 
        {
            list.Add(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
        }
}
foreach (var _PO_No in list)
{

        ds= ShippingData_Export(_PO_No);

}


private DataSet ShippingData_Export(string X_PO_NO)
{
    var ds = new DataSet();
    var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strConStr);
    try
    {
        sqlConn.Open();
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_TBL_PO_M_ShippingExcel", sqlConn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@X_PO_NO", X_PO_NO);
        var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        sqlConn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    return ds;
}
```

If we select more than 1 _PO_No , then we only get the last value after looping.
So my question is how to store DataSet value after end loop.
For example: If we select 2 _PO_No : GV01 and GV02 then after ending loop . We will get both 2 _PO_No  not only the last one (GV02)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is:

```
foreach (var _PO_No in list)
{
    ds = ShippingData_Export(_PO_No);
}
```

You are looping through your list and calling `ShippingData_Export` on each item in the list but you're then overwriting `ds` each time you call this method. This is why only the last value is stored.

If you want to have a single `DataSet` contain multiple results, you need to pass your `DataSet` to the `ShippingData_Export` method and add your results to it instead of creating a new one each time.

The result would be something like this:

```
foreach (var _PO_No in list)
{
    ShippingData_Export(_PO_No, ds);
}

private void ShippingData_Export(string X_PO_NO, DataSet ds)
{
    var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strConStr);
    try
    {
        sqlConn.Open();
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_TBL_PO_M_ShippingExcel", sqlConn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@X_PO_NO", X_PO_NO);
        var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        sqlConn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    return ds;
}
```

A couple of other small issues with your code:

- Add { } to the block after the line `if (Convert.ToBoolean(chk.Value) == true)`. Get used to using { } explicitly to make your code more readable.
- You are manually opening your SQL Connection but you don't close it when an exception happens. Look into the [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) to make sure you always close your connection even when things go wrong.

Comment: Sorry, But I still do not know how to have a single DataSet contain multiple results in my case. Please explain more!  I need this DataSet to export data to Excel !Thanks!

Comment: @user3035133 I've added some code to demonstrate the end result. Does that help?